# Angular : CORS problem when loading external script or ressource

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, cors

Under my angular App , i'm using renderer2 to load some javascript ressources by injecting them to the head of window

That s working fine but ;

When serving locally , this loading the ressource fails since there is a CORS problem :

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://website/src/style1.css' from
> origin 'http://192.168.244.128:3001' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> Request header field x-requested-with is not allowed by
> Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Note : i'm running my Angular app in my local machine but i'm using some url redirection since it's a vmware virtual machin , that's why my local url is : **http://192.168.244.128:3001**

I ve tried to use an Angular proxy like this :

**proxy.conf.json :**

```
{
  "/*": {
    "target": "https://website/src/style1.css",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

But the problem persists

**Suggestions ??**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

target should be a domain server + port but not a direct resource path

```
"target": "https://{domain}:{port}"
```

I also advice you to use a url keyword to identify external requests  (in my sample below i choose "resources")

For sample if you want to access

```
https://website/src/style1.css
```

you have to access it by

`localhost:{localport}/resources/src/style1.css` or `resources/src/style1.css`

here a proxy config

```
{
    "/resources/*": {
      "target": "https://website",
      "secure": false,
      "changeOrigin": true,
      "pathRewrite": {
        "^/resources": ""
      },
      "logLevel": "debug"
    }
  }
```